# What does 'bottomRight' mean when using dataChanged() with a QTreeView in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

It's straight forward to understand the topLeft and bottomRight QModelIndex when using `dataChanged(const QModelIndex & topLeft, const QModelIndex & bottomRight)`signal with a `QTableView`, but I'm confused with `bottomRight` when using `dataChanged()` with a `QTreeView`.

What does `bottomRight` exactly mean?

Can I update the whole tree view by just `emit datachanged()` signal once?

Comment: This signal is emitted whenever the data in an existing item changes.

If the items are of the same parent, the affected ones are those between topLeft and bottomRight inclusive. If the items do not have the same parent, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: // update the whole tree views.
    emit dataChanged(QModelIndex(), QModelIndex());

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `dataChanged()` signal from a model updates the view. The code `emit` `dataChanged(QModelIndex(), QModelIndex())` will update the whole tree view. The call of tree view's `update()` doesn't work.

Code:

```
// update the whole tree views.
emit dataChanged(QModelIndex(), QModelIndex());
```

Comment: Generally avoid code-only answers.  Consider adding a `description`.  Thanks

Comment: the `dataChanged()` signal from a model update the view. The code `emit dataChanged(QModelIndex(), QModelIndex())` update the whole tree view. The call of tree view's update() doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks.  I have incorporated your description into your answer.  Feel free to revise as needed.  Welcome to SO by the way! :)

Comment: please be warned that if you are using a proxy model on top of your source model, emitting dataChanged with default constructed indexes from your source model will not cause the view to update (the proxy model wont forward the dataChanged signal if either one of the indexes are invalid)

Comment: Thanks, @CsabaTorda. Good to know.  I am using a proxy/filtered view on my model and have this issue.  So, if you are using a proxy model, what is the best way to update the entire view?

Comment: Hey Devan, I defined a custom signal in my model and connected it to the `dataChanged` slot of my view. I just emit the signal whenever I need the view to be updated entirely

Answer (score 0):

The `dataChanged()` signal has the same meaning for both table views and tree views. However if changed items in tree view have different parents, the behavior is undefined.

WRT your question about updating the whole tree view, the answer is no, you cannot update it by emitting this signal. The `dataChanged()` signal emitted **after** the model has been updated.

Comment: And what I'm confused with is if I set the `topLeft` parameter of `dataChanged()` to the root item **row 0** and **column 0**, and `bottomRight` to the **last item** of the tree model, of course using `QModelIndex` iterator, will the whole tree view be updated or what will happen and why?

Comment: @user1636288, sorry, I should say "...signal emitted after the **model** has been updated" - model, not view. I have fixed the text now. As Qt docs say http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8-snapshot/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged, if your first item and last item are of different parents, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for answering. In my opinion `dataChanged()` signal is used for notify the view to update itself without calling the `update()` function of the whole window, and `dataChanged()` signal is auto connected to the view's `dataChanged()` slot in view's `setModel()` function.